# Highcharts how to add an extra value to a bar

Tags: highcharts

The goal is to make a bar chart like this one in the picture showing the values in percentage but also in MillionTonnes:
[image]

The bars are representing the percentage value. The value of the million tonnes is just extra information. Both values can go at the end of the bar and the percentage should appear first and then the Million Tonnes value. Something like: 
49% (49.6 Million Tonnes). How can I make this two values appear at the end of the bar? This is the code I have. TIA

```js
Highcharts.chart('grafica1', {
  chart: {
    type: 'column',
    inverted: true,
    plotBackgroundColor: null,
    plotBorderWidth: 0,
    plotShadow: false
  },
  title: {
    text: ' '
  },
  xAxis: {
    type: 'category',
    labels: {
      useHTML: true
    }
  },
  yAxis: {
    min: 0,
    max: 100,
    title: {
      text: null,
    },
    labels: {
      enabled: false,
    }
  },
  legend: {
    enabled: false
  },
  tooltip: {
    enabled: false
  },
  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      borderWidth: 0,
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        format: '({point.y:.1f} Million tones)%'
      }
    }
  },
  responsive: {
    rules: [{
      condition: {
        maxWidth: 500
      },
      chartOptions: {
        chart: {
          inverted: false
        },
        legend: {
          align: 'center',
          verticalAlign: 'bottom',
          layout: 'horizontal'
        }
      }
    }]
  },
  series: [{
    name: 'Production',
    colorByPoint: true,
    data: [{
      name: 'PACKAGING PAPERS<br>AND BOARDS',
      y: 49,
      color: '#005eb8',
    }, {
      name: 'CASE MATERIALS',
      y: 29.9,
      color: '#fff',
      borderWidth: 2,
      borderColor: '#005eb8'
    }, {
      name: 'OTHER PACKAGING & PAPER',
      y: 14.4,
      color: '#fff',
      borderWidth: 2,
      borderColor: '#005eb8'
    }, {
      name: 'WRAPPINGS',
      y: 4.7,
      color: '#fff',
      borderWidth: 2,
      borderColor: '#005eb8'
    }]
  }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<div id="grafica1" class="chart1Slide2"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the `stacking` option ([Doc](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.stackLabels)) it's possible.

Here a working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/core972/1LvrfL8n/)